# Line replacement in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I am a new coder who is getting some training parttime in Python 3, and I have recently been given a homework assignment to write a program that allows a user to enter a name of the file, enter the text they want changed in the file, and then change it.
I have written some code, and am experimenting with the "r+" functionality, however my code just does not seem to be working.  The line I keep attempting to change in a little .txt file I have for testing does not change
If anyone could give me some tips, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
# Build main

def main():
# Get file name and open for reading and writing
    toalter = input("Please enter a target file: ")
    infile = open(toalter, "r+")
# Get input of the line to be changed, and what it is to change to
    old = input("Please enter the text you want to change: ")
    new = input("Please enter what you want it changed to: ")

    for line in infile:
        if old in line:
            line = line.replace(old, new)
    infile.close()
main()
```

Comment: Hint: Files are never line-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

1. You replaced the old string with new but you never call a statement to write it to "toalter" file.
2. You cannot open a file for read and write at the same time but you can open to read, do something with that data, and then open it again to overwrite.

Assuming I have a test.txt file that contains the following.  I wanted to replace Apple with Coconut.  This is how I approach it.

```
Apple
Orange
Strawberry
Kiwi

>>> def replace (old, new):
...     path = '/testfiles/test.txt'
...     with open (path) as f:
...         file = f.read ()
...     if old in file:
...         file = file.replace (old, new)
...     with open (path, 'w') as f:
...         f.write (file)
...         
>>> 
>>> replace ('Apple', 'Coconut')
```

**Output**

```
Coconut
Orange
Strawberry
Kiwi
```

If you have a file containing multiple instances of Apple, then you'll need to change your logic to this.

```
def replace (old, new):
...     newstring = ''
...     path = '/testfiles/test.txt'
...     with open (path) as f:
...         for line in f:
...             if old in line:
...                 newstring += line.replace (old, new)
...             else:
...                 newstring += line
...     with open (path, 'w') as f:
...         f.write (newstring)
...         
>>>
```